# Sentry release versions

Tags: sentry

I have `gitlab` integration and I am trying to configure release versions. I used `sentry-cli` to create release and associate commits. I used `sentry-cli releases propose-version` to get SHA-1 and set it like release version. My version in `SDK` must me equal this SHA-1 return or I can use any custom version name?

Comment: Same question here. The documentation I could find is not clear about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Version set from `sentry-cli` and version in `sdk` must be equal. That allows you to link the error with the release.